# prove sequence is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence where $(a_{2n}) \le (a_{2n+2})$ and $(a_{2n+1}) \ge (a_{2n+3})$, i have to prove that $a_n$ is covergent if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ ($a_{n+1}- a_n)$=0.

now i proved that if $a_n$ is convergent then lim $(a_{n+1} - a_n)$=0 by proving that if $a_n$ is convergent to limit L then $a_{n+k}$ is also  convergent to L, but im not sure how to prove that if the limit=0 then $a_n$ is convergent, i know i have to do something with the sub-sequences since thats where im at, but im not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Hints: $(a_{2n})$ is increasing and $(a_{2n+1})$ is decreasing.  If $a_{n+1}-a_n <1$  for $n \ge k$ then $a_{2n}\le a_{2n+2}<a_{2n+1}+1 \le a_3+1$ as long as $2n+1\ge k$. Thus, $(a_{2n})$ is bounded above. Similarly, $(a_{2n+1})$ is bounded below. These sequences have  limits. Show that the two limits are equal.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not quiet following you, but wouldn't it be $a_{2n+1} +1 \le a_3 +1$ since the n starts at 1? also is there a specific reaosn we're assuming $a_{n+1} - a_n \lt 1$ ? thanks

Comment: Less than any  $\epsilon$ will be fine. You are right about $a_3+1$. @S. M